# ROS Answers SE migration: IMU selection

Tags: imu, navigation, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm just getting started with the robot_localization package and may aim is to fuse odometry and IMU data for a [car like robot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uy6GlW2qXj0). I have an odometry sensor setup, but was wondering if there was an IMU someone suggests using for easy integration with robot_localization package.

I currently have a [vn-100](http://www.vectornav.com/products/vn100-rugged), but have been having a lot of difficulty with just getting it to give repeatable values. I am using the [driver](https://github.com/KumarRobotics/imu_vn_100), but the orientation seems to differ at the beginning of every time the imu is initialized.

Is the VN-100 a good IMU for my robot platform, or would another IMU be easier to integrate with ROS and robot_localization?

Also, should gravity be included in the IMU reading for accelerations?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243726/imu-selection/) by [matthewlefort](https://answers.ros.org/users/27978/matthewlefort/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2016-09-13

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just make sure that the IMU produces data in ENU frame. Most IMUs produce NED-frame data by default, which will not work with `r_l`. I may be incorrect, but looking at the VN-100 driver [source](https://github.com/KumarRobotics/imu_vn_100/blob/master/src/imu_vn_100.cpp#L328), it appears to be copying data straight from the IMU, which indicates to me that it may be in the wrong frame. Please correct me if you find that's not accurate.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2016-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are several IMU available which can be interfaced with ROS.For the list of IMU ,visit this page
[ROS Sensors](http://wiki.ros.org/Sensors).

I haven't worked with VN-100 sensor so I don't know how accurate the sensor is when compared to others.
I have worked with [razor imu from sparkfun](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10736).
It was good and easy to integrate and the packages are available in this [ROS razor](http://wiki.ros.org/razor_imu_9dof)

---

Originally posted by [Gokul](https://answers.ros.org/users/25955/gokul/) with karma: 243 on 2016-09-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [matthewlefort](https://answers.ros.org/users/27978/matthewlefort/) on 2016-09-19**:
Great list! Thank you